# Check if text binded to a control is null

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to check if I'm binding a null data on a controller. If the data is null, I need to not show the label as well as the binded data.

Below is my code right now.

```
var oMatNrRow1 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutRow();
    control1 = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
    text : Appcc.getText("MATERIAL_NO") + ":"
});

matrixCell1 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell();
matrixCell1.addContent(control1);
control = new sap.ui.commons.Label();
control.bindProperty("text", "matnr");

matrixCell1.addContent(control);
oMatNrRow1.addCell(matrixCell1);
vendorTable.addRow(oMatNrRow1);
```

I have tried control.getProperty("text") but it only returns null when it should have return a number if matnr is not null.

I also tried formatter. I will have no problem with formatter if matnr is not null. But if it is null, the point is to destroy/delete contents of both matrixCell1 instances. In my code below, addition of matrixCell1 content will still push through.

```
...
formatter: function(matnr){
   if (matnr !== ''){
       return contract
   } else{
       matrixCell.destroyContent();
   }
});

matrixCell1.addContent(control);
oMatNrRow1.addCell(matrixCell1);
vendorTable.addRow(oMatNrRow1);
```

Not sure if you can move the ff code inside if statement

```
matrixCell1.addContent(control);
oMatNrRow1.addCell(matrixCell1);
vendorTable.addRow(oMatNrRow1);
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It would be more easy to bind the visible property of both controls to the matnr like this: `control.bindProperty("visible", { path: "matnr", formatter: function(matnr){ return !!matnr; } });`. Do you really need to destroy the controls?

Comment: Though I found a workaround on my problem, I will also try this. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to user the visible property.
Are you aware of conditional binding of UI5? Using them you do not need the formatter at all in that case. [see](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround on my issue. It was a simple if else condition. For the if statement, I just added `data[j].matnr` and it worked! I also noticed that this was how SAP implemented the behavior also e.g. `oSearchViewData.description`.